# My array filters out numbers if there are letters, but won't if there are only numbers

Tags: c

I would like to know what causes this? Shouldn't the code swap the numbers for '\0' like it does when i put letters in?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int 
main()
{
    char string[256] = "12356";
    //gets(string);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(string[i]))
        {
            for (; j < strlen(string); j++)
            {
                if(!isdigit(string[i+j]))
                {
                    string[i] = string[i+j];
                    string[i+j] = '0';
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 


    }



    printf("%s", string);

}
```

̶A̶̶̶ ̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶f̶̶̶e̶̶̶s̶̶̶s̶̶̶o̶̶̶r̶̶̶ ̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶ ̶̶̶m̶̶̶y̶̶̶ ̶̶̶u̶̶̶n̶̶̶i̶̶̶v̶̶̶e̶̶̶r̶̶̶s̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶y̶̶̶ ̶̶̶a̶̶̶s̶̶̶s̶̶̶i̶̶̶g̶̶̶n̶̶̶e̶̶̶d̶̶̶ ̶̶̶u̶̶̶s̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶o̶̶̶ ̶̶̶d̶̶̶o̶̶̶ ̶̶̶v̶̶̶a̶̶̶r̶̶̶i̶̶̶o̶̶̶u̶̶̶s̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶k̶̶̶s̶̶̶ ̶̶̶w̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶o̶̶̶u̶̶̶t̶̶̶ ̶̶̶u̶̶̶s̶̶̶i̶̶̶n̶̶̶g̶̶̶ ̶̶̶a̶̶̶d̶̶̶d̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶i̶̶̶o̶̶̶n̶̶̶a̶̶̶l̶̶̶ ̶̶̶s̶̶̶t̶̶̶r̶̶̶i̶̶̶n̶̶̶g̶̶̶s̶̶̶ ̶̶̶a̶̶̶n̶̶̶d̶̶̶ ̶̶̶n̶̶̶o̶̶̶w̶̶̶ ̶̶̶I̶̶̶'̶̶̶m̶̶̶ ̶̶̶q̶̶̶u̶̶̶e̶̶̶s̶̶̶t̶̶̶i̶̶̶o̶̶̶n̶̶̶i̶̶̶n̶̶̶g̶̶̶ ̶̶̶l̶̶̶i̶̶̶f̶̶̶e̶̶̶.̶̶̶

Found a better solution to the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string);i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(string[i]))
        {
            for(int j=i; string[j]!='\0'; j++)
                {
                string[j] = string[j+1];
                }
            i--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "now I'm questioning life" Well, then you're in luck: the answer to life is 42

Comment: The only part of your code that modifies the string is contained in an if that checks if `!isdigit(some character of the string)`. Seems logical that it would never modify the string if there aren't any non-digit characters :)

Comment: I expected it to swap places with the '\0' at the end of the string.

If I use "12sample12string" it will leave me with "samplestring"
But, if there are only numbers "12" stays "12".

Comment: Just before the end of execution, the string looks like "samplestring0000".
How does it end up like "samplestring" if it doesn't swap with '\0'?

Comment: you get past the end of the string with `i + j`. This is not what you want.

Comment: @BlažČulina `'0'` is not the same as `'\0'`. `'0'` is a character with an associated numerical value. `'\0'` is a terminating null with a value of zero.

Comment: Never put a call to `strlen` in a loop test (unless you want it to run as slow as possible).  Common sense.  Anyone grading this as an assignment should immediately take off points for that.

Comment: @JoshuaYonathan The `'0'` is used so it doesn't leave an additional letter in the string.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. If you use `char string[256] = "12356";` what do you expect your result to be? You do not need `string.h` or `strlen()` for anything you are doing. Simply iterate over the string with `for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)`

Comment: **Note:** `string[j] = string[j+1];` does not **swap** characters, it simply overwrites the current with the next.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)` and `for (; j < strlen(string); j++)`  The function: `strlen()` returns type: `size_t`.   The two statements compare a `size_t` with an `int`  I.E. comparing a unsigned long int with a signed int.  You should not perform such actions in your code. Suggest declaring both `j` and `i` as `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: Note: function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed since about 2009.  Suggest using `fgets()` (which does have a different set of parameters

Comment: once the code removes a number, it needs to loop back to check for any other number.  And don't do anything like this: `string[i+j] = '0';` until after the whole string has been checked

Comment: regarding: `if(!isdigit(string[i+j]))`  since the variable `j` has not been reset with each inner loop,  the sum of `i` + `j` can/will quickly reach beyond the end of the string.

Comment: suggest: using variable `i` as the 'destination index.  using variable `j` as the source index and move one character at a time until at the end of the string.  Each time a source character gets moved, increment the destination index.  When all done stepping through the source, then set the string terminator using the destination index

Comment: I realise a lot of this code is outdated and isn't used in modern C. Sadly, I'm not being taught modern C.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what was happening is that when there were only numbers, the program couldn't reach the `'\0'` at the end of the string.

To fix that, `int j = 0` is needed inside the loop (instead of outside)

also the`j < strlen(string)`  must be `j <= strlen(string)` in this case.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(string[i]))
        {
            for (; j <= strlen(string); j++)
            {
                if(!isdigit(string[i+j]))
                {
                    string[i] = string[i+j];
                    string[i+j] = '0';
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I thank you all.